# Should we retag gearbox related questions using the gear tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have just created the [gearbox](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gearbox) tag for [my question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/20972/occasional-crunch-grinding-noise-when-shifting-into-first-gear-at-speed).

It seems strange that there isnt one. The [gears](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gears) tag has [many](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/19025/after-long-journeys-gear-slips-in-5th-but-not-into-neutral) [gearbox](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/18489/reverse-gear-doesnt-work-anymore-on-an-automatic) [related](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/16985/ford-transit-not-going-into-1st-gear-easily) [questions](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/16871/replacing-3rd-gear-synchro-on-a-tacoma).

Should I/we retag the [gearbox](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gearbox) tag for these sort of questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No your question should be [transmission](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transmission)